# Change of vector fields between different manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

I've read a bunch of books about differential geometry and topology, but some questions came up about the nature of vector fields and their connection to smooth manifolds.
Suppose that there is a certain vector field **V** defined at each point **p** in a smooth manifold **M**, that is homeomorphic to another manifold **N**. Few questions:

- What is the transformation law from vector field **V** on **M** to the vector field **W** on **N**?
- How will the lenght of a vector **v** in **M** change, when there is a new metric tensor in **N** [is there any rule of transition]?

Thank you.

Comment: If you assume the existence of a diffeomorphism $\phi : M \to N$, you can define $W$ using the differential of $\phi$, i.e. $W \colon = d\phi \circ V$. If you have a Riemannian metric $g_N$ on $N$, then the length of $W$ is $g_N(W,W) = g_N(d\phi(V), d\phi(V))$. Note that if there is a metric $g_M$ on $M$ and if $\phi$ is also an isometry, then you have:  $g_N(W,W) = g_M(V,V)$.

Comment: Thank you, your insight into isometry is life saving. I've just found about f-relatedness between diffeomorfic manifolds and in fact an interesting characteristic is that this relation between vetor fields is unique, according to the 6.5 theorem on [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Differentiable_Manifolds/Diffeomorphisms_and_related_vector_fields).